# How to check if a UNWIND parameter exists in Neo4J Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J Cypher query where in some cases some parameters might not exist.

So, for example, in this part of the statement:

```
UNWIND statement.mentionsRelations as mentionsRelation 
MATCH (c:Concept{name:mentionsRelation.name})
```

I want to proceed to `MATCH` only if `mentionsRelation.name` exists.

How do I add this check?

I tried with `CASE` but I think I'm placing it at a wrong place...

Thank you!

Comment: If `MATCH` does not... match, the rest query would not execute. Is that a behaviour you want to avoid? What would be the rest of the query?

Comment: Yes, I want to continue the query even if `MATCH ` doesn't match. The rest is a long query that continues with more `MATCH` clauses and other stuff.

Comment: I actually then call a `CREATE` clause to save a certain connection and then another `MATCH` and `CREATE` query for a different connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use OPTIONAL MATCH.  If there is no match is found, then it will use NULL for the missing part of the pattern. It is similar to outer join in SQL.

```
NEW:
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Concept{name:mentionsRelation.name}) 

OLD:
MATCH (c:Concept{name:mentionsRelation.name})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use `apoc.do.when` where you can specify a query if the predicate matches and one if it doesn't, for eg :

```
WITH [{mentions: [], count:10}, {mentions: []}] AS params
UNWIND params AS parameter
CALL apoc.do.when(parameter.count IS NOT NULL, 'RETURN null AS c', 'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN count(n) AS c')
YIELD value
RETURN value

╒══════════╕
│"value"   │
╞══════════╡
│{"c":null}│
├──────────┤
│{"c":10}  │
└──────────┘
```